# Is it posible to reset all statistic in Fabric.io?

Tags: android, google-fabric

I need to reset all statistic for my app in fabric.
To make it look, like it is first time i'v attached fabric to my application.
Thank you!

I'v tried to delete app from fabric, but data was not deleted after app was inited again.

Answer (score 3):

Mike from Fabric here. We don't have a full reset option currently, but you could achieve it by creating a new organization and using the different API key and Build Secret to make it a new app with no historical data.

Comment: would love this feature.  Or better yet since that could be a security threat (someone hacks you and deletes all your data :(!) You guys should make a flag for an app in development, and a flag for production.  That way I can test my apps (and test fabric implementation) then switch the flag to production when I release without have bogus stats or needing to create a new org.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We also separate out apps by bundle id or package name, so if you have .debug append to your dev build, the data will be kept separate.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I can't, for various reasons, change the bundle ID. Would it work to delete the app from Fabric, and then add it again?

Comment: Yes, but your existing data would be removed.

Comment: we need that kind of function ! should be simple for fabric to provide a button which resets everything :)

Comment: Given Fabric's upcoming retirement, there aren't plans to add this.